# How to use WITH subqueries as a list of options in WHERE clause in standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, subquery

**Whats the problem**

I have a very large list of results. I want to filter my query to only include a small sub-set of those based on the most popular results within the table.

When I put my filtering subquery in the `WITH` clause it doesn't work. But if I put it directly in the WHERE clause it does work. Why?

I'd prefer the first for clarity, but I can't get it to work.

I'm working in BigQuery with StandardSQL.

**Example**

```
WITH
  most_common AS (
  SELECT
    page
  FROM
    `mydataset`
  LIMIT 
    100
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
   `mydataset`
WHERE
  page IN most_common
```

Here I'm trying to get all the results, where the page is in the first 100 rows.

It returns the following error:
 - `Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier "most_common" at [12:12]`

However if I put the subquery directly in the where it works fine.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
   `mydataset`
WHERE
  page IN (
  SELECT
    page
  FROM
    `mydataset`
  LIMIT 
    100
)
```

**My limited understanding**

It says it wants unnest, but unnest turns an array to a table result as a sub-query this should already be a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  most_common AS (
  SELECT
    page
  FROM
    `mydataset`
  LIMIT 
    100
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
   `mydataset`
WHERE
  page IN (SELECT page FROM most_common)
```

Another option:

```
#standardSQL
WITH most_common AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(page) pages FROM (
    SELECT page
    FROM `mydataset`
    LIMIT 100
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM `mydataset`, most_common
WHERE page IN UNNEST(pages)
```

or slightly refactored version

```
#standardSQL
WITH most_common AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(page LIMIT 100) pages 
  FROM `mydataset`
)
SELECT *
FROM `mydataset`, most_common
WHERE page IN UNNEST(pages)
```

Note: `ARRAY_AGG(...)` accepts ORDER BY clause so you can actually pick most common using this syntax `ARRAY_AGG(page ORDER BY some metric DESC LIMIT 100)`
Obviously final version depends on your real use case  - but rather than this - you got the idea I hope

Answer (score 0):

When you write query with CTE expression data will be return in table format. You can use CTE expression in sub query to work.

```
WITH MYSELECT AS (SELECT
  status
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_request`
LIMIT 100)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_request` WHERE status IN (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM MYSELECT);
```